# Great expectation validation results operations

Tags: postgresql, validation, etl, great-expectations

Is there a way to split the data a batch in two streams of data:

1. one for which the expectations are met
2. The second one for which expectations fail

That is to split the tested batch of data into two table/pandas data frames? one that is clean and the other that is not?
I am trying to use great expectations with Postgres tables as data source in an ETL pipeline.
The only thing is that I wouldn't want to fail the entire ETL process just quarantine the data that fails the test cases.